# hiredis "undefined reference to" compiler error

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, libevent, hiredis

I want to compile the client for redis in C. I've downloaded and installed the libevent library and the hiredis files. I've used this command:

```
gcc -I/home/tasos/Dropbox/lists/hiredis example-libevent.c -levent
```

but I get these errors:

```
/tmp/ccxoerYJ.o: In function `redisLibeventReadEvent':
example-libevent.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `redisAsyncHandleRead'
/tmp/ccxoerYJ.o: In function `redisLibeventWriteEvent':
example-libevent.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `redisAsyncHandleWrite'
/tmp/ccxoerYJ.o: In function `getCallback':
example-libevent.c:(.text+0x2d2): undefined reference to `redisAsyncDisconnect'
/tmp/ccxoerYJ.o: In function `main':
example-libevent.c:(.text+0x393): undefined reference to `redisAsyncConnect'
example-libevent.c:(.text+0x3f3): undefined reference to `redisAsyncSetConnectCallback'
example-libevent.c:(.text+0x404): undefined reference to `redisAsyncSetDisconnectCallback'
example-libevent.c:(.text+0x45d): undefined reference to `redisAsyncCommand'
example-libevent.c:(.text+0x47d): undefined reference to `redisAsyncCommand'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

why isn't this working?

Comment: thanks, it printed fewer error

Comment: thanks, compiled succesfully. Where could I have found those compile options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-levent` and `-lhiredis` compile option in command.

Comment: I am trying the following >>> gcc -c redismake.c -levent -lhiredis -I'/home/ubuntu/workspace/c/hiredis' 
gcc redismake.o -o redismake <<< and I get this error: redismake.o: In function `main':
redismake.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `redisConnect'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.   Any thoughts ?!